# Customizing a shortcut for the UV Editor no longer works in 2.8+

Tags: shortcut, customization

Customizing a shortcut to **Snap Cursor to Selected** *in the UV Editor* used to work in 2.79

The syntax to define this shortcut is no longer working in 2.8+

That syntax is: `uv.snap_cursor`

[image]

After typing it in, the Target drop-down selector appears, indicating that Blender still recognizes the command on some level.

Furthermore, after performing this action using the standard <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (and Pie Menu) the Console indicates that the command has not changed. It just doesn't seem to be assignable to a keyboard shortcut anymore.

[image]

What needs to be changed for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: @RobertGützkow You were right! I had created the shortcut in the wrong section. *(facepalm)* It's working for me now. Thank you! If you post an answer, I'll accept. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut has to be created in the correct category otherwise it won't work. For the UV Editor that is: *Image > UV Editor > UV Editor (Global)*

[image: UV Editor global shortcuts]